# A DLL function must be called on a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll

I have a dll function `Copy(const char** srcFiles, const char* dst)` which copies `srcFiles` to the folder `dst`. And it must, for example, every 0.01 sec. send copy progress information (in per cent) to my own function `CopyProgress`. The problem is that I can't change `Copy` function code, so I think execution of this function on a different thread would be a good idea. But I am a beginner in multithreading and can't imagine how this can be done.

Any ideas, hints? Thank You.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, multithreading isn't automatically the solution to every programming problem, and is often overused.  If you can't change `Copy`, and it doesn't have a means for a progress hook/callback, then there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should really consider changing `Copy` to give you progress information via a callback. But if you absolutely must do without changing `Copy`, you'll have to run it in another thread using [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then periodically scan the destination directory to see how much has been copied (every 0.01 second is probably too fast to be practical for this method - if you need this much granularity you must add some hooks to `Copy`).

Comment: The FindXXXXChangeNotification API will likely greatly assist in doing what bdonian is talking about. It is NOT trivial to setup, but the very nature of the OP's question regarding monitoring copying files may well be his bailout. Were this a general-solution question, the OP would likely be SOL, but since it is a file copy (copies, actually), you can exploit the OS system calls Windows to help you out.